# Scalar Value Function returns VARCHAR(MAX) in C++ ADO (not .NET)

Tags: c++, sql-server, adodb

I created a scalar-valued function in MSSQL that returns VARCHAR(MAX).

I am using a CommandPtr (preCom) filled with the parameters for the function, and I am calling the function with the following call:

```
_variant_t vNull;
vNull.vt = VT_ERROR;
vNull.scode = DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND;
HRESULT hr = ptrCom->raw_Execute(&vNull, &vNull, adCmdStoredProc, &record_set);
```

The returned HRESULT is DB_E_ERRORSINCOMMAND.

If I change the returned value from VARCHAR(MAX) to VARCHAR(8000) everything works fine.

Does anyone have any idea how do I execute a scalar-valued function that returned VARCHAR(MAX) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Updating an Application to SQL Server Native Client from MDAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131035.aspx):

> When MDAC applications connect to SQL Server, the data types introduced in SQL Server 2005 will appear as SQL Server 2000-compatible data types as shown in the following table.

```
SQL Server 2005 type SQL Server 2000 type
varchar(max)         text
```

So I'd guess if you can specify `text`, it might work.

Comment: Hey, thanks for you help :-)
When I'm trying to set TEXT as return data-type I am getting this error from the SQL:

"The text data type is invalid for return values." :-(

Comment: @strDisplayName - then I think you'll have to move on from ADO. It can't understand `varchar(max)`. The modern programming interface is SQL Native Client, which I've already handily provided one link to the documentation :-|